# Why does the 1st C code result in one variable and the 2nd in 3 variables. Is there a way to make the first program work by slight changes?

Tags: c, function, declaration

Could anyone help understand why mine results in 20100 while the second results in 3 values as it should to help me with future programs? I am all new to programming and C.

My version

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{   
    int toes
    toes = 10;
    
    int x,y;
    
    x= toes * 2;
    printf ("%d", x);
    y= toes * toes;
    printf ("%d", y);
}
```

Right version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int toes;
    toes = 10;
    printf("toes = %d\n", toes);
    
    printf("Twice toes = %d\n", 2 * toes);
    printf("toes squared = %d\n", toes * toes);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just add a space or a newline after you print something. `printf ("%d\n", x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are right. The only thing you're missing is a linebreak to separate between the `20` and the `100`:

```
x= toes * 2;
printf ("%d\n", x);
/* Here----^ */
y= toes * toes;
printf ("%d\n", y);
/* And Here^ */
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Such an amateur mistake, don't know how I didn't see this! Appreciate your help :-)!!

Comment: @Hala please accept answers that solve the problem. This way future readers can refer to the right solution and the question gets marked as "answered"

Comment: Done! Had no idea about this function :). Thanks again!